# turn off Hardware acceleration in iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, hardware-acceleration

I use a `UITextView` to show some arabic text in my app. On some devices the text is not clear. Some experts told me to turn off hardware acceleration for the app. The text is rendering not rendered in a `UIWebView`.

Can any one help me to turnoff hardware acceleration for the app?

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample image of the “not clear” text.

Answer (score 1):

You cant and it is not the source of the problem.

Disabling Hardwareacceleration was a Android workarround for some rendering problems. Your "expert" missed the detail that you develop on iOS.

Some devices that are currently supported by iOS 7 & 8 have no retina display - hence less pixel to display crisp text. Can you pin down the devices that doesnt show the text as they should to a specific iOS or device type/family?

Edit for feedback:
iPad mini 1 has no retina display. Texts in general look less sharp and crisp. On an iPad 2 would the display size help, but the first iPad Mini feels often less good to read. There is sadly only one option:
Increase the textbox and fontsize some.

Comment: iPad mini is having this issue.

Comment: Mini 1 has no retina display. Texts in general look less sharp and crisp. Increase the textbox and fintsize some might be an option.